# The right way for dynamic ssh port-forwarding

Tags: ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

Want my Firefox could use localhost:9099 proxy forwarded from vps server, why it doesn't  it work this way? I always get `bind: Address already in use`

```
$ ssh -vfND 127.0.0.2:9099 vpn 
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: Host  is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: Local connections to 127.0.0.2:9099 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.2 port 9099.
bind: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener: cannot listen to port: 9099
debug1: Local connections to 127.1:8080 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: forking to background
```

I add the next step in my solution of problem. The duplicate binding is solved 
it was a question of firewall on local machine now i can get connected to my vps server. But proxy in browser still doesn't work when i open a http in browser i get

```
The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure  that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

and on remote machine (VPS) i get the next

```
debug1: Connection to port 9099 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 6 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: have 837
debug2: channel 2: zombie
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: dynamic-tcpip, nchannels 3
```

**on remote machine**

```
# iptables -L -n -v

       state NEW tcp dpt:9099
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0              122 19030 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

## netstat -lntp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1283/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55964           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      848/rpc.statd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      837/rpcbind         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5750/ssh            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9099          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5750/ssh            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:46165           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1568/skype          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      853/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: The TCP / IP stack does not allow two processes to listen on the same socket (port + host IP).  The message is telling you some other process already has `localhost:9099` so ssh can't have it.  You can use a different port or find and kill the other process.

Comment: Ok, no matter which port i try to use i give the same error

Comment: Do you really have processes listening on every single port?

Comment: what output is produced by 'netstat -lntp'?

Comment: local ssh daemon listen
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9099            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4779/ssh

Comment: just tryed with next 4444 port

Comment: Connection to port 4444 forwarding to socks port 0 debug1: channel 1: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 1: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 1: pre_dynamic: have 638
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: dynamic-tcpip, nchannels 2
debug1: Connection to port 4444 forwarding to socks debug2: fd 5 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 1: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 1: pre_dynamic: have 1061
debug2: channel 1: zombie
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: dynamic-tcpi

Comment: Can you share the output of `netstat`, as requested?

Comment: The error you're getting says `address already in use`, it'd be nice to rule out that possibility before trying to find other explanations...

Comment: alredy in use is SOLVED, ran into next problem